# Metrics for scatter plot\ random distribution

Tags: python, statistics, data-analysis, correlation, metrics

During my Data analysis process, I want to demonstrate that 2 variables have 0 correlation with each other,

the scatter plot loo like the following picture

Which metrics can I choose to show that the 2 variables don't have a correlation?

I know that there are pearson correlation ( R^2)
but there are other metrices?

[random distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEdH0.png)

Comment: please attach a picture or the data.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).